# Sort an Array of Objects based on Occurrence in Javascript and ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Array of objects with the following properties

```
[ 
  { testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},  // 1 = 3 times (Kaka)
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},  // 2 = 5 times (Ramos)
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},  // 3 = 4 times (Messi)
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},  // 4 = 2 times (Neuer)
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},  // 5 = 6 times (Ronaldo)
  { testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '4',name:'Neuer'},
  { testerId: '4',name:'Neuer'},
  { testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
]
```

**Output**: [`Ronaldo`,`Ramos`,`Messi`,`Kaka`,`Neuer`]

It's supposed to be in increasing order of occurrence of `testerId`.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: my question is how to sort array of objects based on occurrence?

Comment: And, what have you tried? Because the output you have shown does not in any way correspond to the array you start with, except the object "name" key have the same elements. Do you want a function that makes a _new_ array given an array of objects? Because then it seems like you should just count the number of objects and compare the counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Map` to help group by `testerId`.

Here is a *functional programming* style implementation:

```js
const myArray = [{ testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},{ testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},{ testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},{ testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},{ testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},{ testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},{ testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},{ testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},{ testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},{ testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},{ testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},{ testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},{ testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},{ testerId: '4',name:'Neuer'},{ testerId: '4',name:'Neuer'},{ testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},{ testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},{ testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},{ testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},{ testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'}]

const result = Array.from(
    myArray.reduce((map, item) => 
        (map.get(item.testerId).count++, map) 
    , new Map(myArray.map(o => 
        [o.testerId, Object.assign({}, o, { count: 0 })]
    ))), ([k, o]) => o
).sort( (a, b) => b.count - a.count )
.map( o => o.name );

console.log(result);
```

### Explanation

Some have commented that they find this hard to read. In my opinion this is a matter of habit and once one becomes familiar with it, such code is not so hard to understand.

So here is an explanation:

The first task consists of creating a Map. The `Map` constructor can take an array of pairs which represent the keys and values. This array is created from `myArray` with the `.map()` method. For each object in `myArray`, the key `testerID` property serves as key, and a copy of the object, extended with a new property `count`, serves as the corresponding value. The (shallow) copy is made with `Object.assign`

This new Map is then passed on to the second argument of the `reduce` method, so it becomes the initial value of the `reduce` callback function. That callback simply increases the appropriate counter property, and returns the mutated map again (using the comma operator).

The result of this `reduce()` call will thus be a map with all the counters set at the right value. This map is then converted back to an array of pairs with `Array.from()`. This method can take a callback function which performs a mapping on those key/value pairs. The `([k, o]) => o` mapping just converts the pairs to the value part, throwing the key away.

This array of values (objects with three properties) is then sorted by descending count property.

Finally, the name is extracted from those objects with a `map`, giving the resulting array of names.

Comment: functional !== hard to read... 
How is OP supposed to learn/understand when you omit almost all white-space? Is it relay necessary to botch it all up into a single blob?

Comment: @trincot, I will definitely try your solution as well. It''s really interesting.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh, I added a section with explanations. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The built in javascript `.sort` method will be helpful here. You can pass it a comparator based on the name counts in your object.

So first create a map of name to number of occurrences, then an array of just the names themselves. Then the sort is pretty straightforward:

```js
const myArray = [ 
  { testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},  // 1 = 3 times (Kaka)
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},  // 2 = 5 times (Ramos)
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},  // 3 = 4 times (Messi)
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},  // 4 = 2 times (Neuer)
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},  // 5 = 6 times (Ronaldo)
  { testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '4',name:'Neuer'},
  { testerId: '4',name:'Neuer'},
  { testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
]

const myArrayCounts = myArray.reduce((counts, item) => {
  if (counts[item.name] === undefined) counts[item.name] = 0;
  counts[item.name]++;
  return counts;
}, {});

const myArrayNames = myArray
  .map(x => x.name)
  .filter((x, i, l) => l.indexOf(x) === i); // Fancy deduplication filter

console.log(myArrayNames.sort((v1, v2) => {return myArrayCounts[v2] - myArrayCounts[v1]}))
```

Comment: thank you very much! Your solution did help me as I was super stuck due to big data I am having.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `set` object and a counter object to keep track of your entries. Then simply sort by the returned count.

```js
let arr = [ 
  { testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},  // 1 = 3 times (Kaka)
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},  // 2 = 5 times (Ramos)
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},  // 3 = 4 times (Messi)
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},  // 4 = 2 times (Neuer)
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},  // 5 = 6 times (Ronaldo)
  { testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '4',name:'Neuer'},
  { testerId: '4',name:'Neuer'},
  { testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
],
mySet = new Set(),
  countObj = {};

for (let obj of arr) {
  if (mySet.has(obj.name)) countObj[obj.name]++;
  else {
    countObj[obj.name] = 1;
    mySet.add(obj.name);
  }
}
arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (countObj[a.name] - countObj[b.name]);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: It's not me. Actually I am trying your solution.

Comment: thank you very much! Your solution did help me as I was super stuck due to big data I am having.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this in 3 steps:

1) Count the # of occurrences for each element in the input.

2) Sort the # of occurrences in descending order.

3) Extract the name field

```js
let input = [ 
  { testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},  
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},  
  { testerId: '3',name:'Messi'},  
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},  
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'}, 
  { testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
  { testerId: '4',name:'Neuer'},
  { testerId: '4',name:'Neuer'},
  { testerId: '1',name:'Kaka'},
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},
  { testerId: '2',name:'Ramos'},
  { testerId: '5',name:'Ronaldo'},
];

//1)
let count = input.reduce((res, val) => {
  if(res[val.name]) {
    res[val.name]++;
  } else {
    res[val.name] = 1;
  }
  return res;
}, {});

let output = Object.entries(count)
  .sort((a, b) => b[1]-a[1]) //2)
  .map(v => v[0]); //3)

console.log(output);
```

Comment: thank you very much! Your explanation is really useful.